# Can I change users on Adobe Draw but transfer my artwork to the new user?

Tags: adobe-draw

I was using an old work account on Adobe without realizing, I no longer have the login for it and was hoping to login as my new account. Can I transfer the artworks to my new account?

Comment: Also I'm using the ipad app if that makes a difference. I would also like to continue adding to the artworks so just saving them would not be ideal.

Comment: Based on [this question](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7334628#7334628) over on the Adobe support site, it looks like the answer is "no, you can't."

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, **no**, moving work between accounts is not supported by Draw.

Source: [Move assets from one account to another](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7334628#7334628)